# Excel: find 'a' or 'b' in a cell

Tags: excel

Using the 'find' formula in Excel, is it possible to say find either 'a' or 'b' in a cell (without using vba)?

For ex;

```
A1 = 'West 1'
```

I tried `Find(OR("1","2"),A1)` but that threw an error.

Comment: `=IFERROR(FIND("1",A1),FIND("2",A1))`

Comment: In other words, no. You cannot put multiple options in a `FIND` function. Might be possible do something similar through other means.

Comment: @simoco Let's say I would like to check from "1" through "9" that would result in a long formula using your approach right?

Comment: you would like only to check whether 1-9 are in A1 or return position of entry?

Comment: @simoco would like to check and return position

Comment: try something like this: `=MIN(IFERROR(FIND({"1","2","3"},A1),9E+307))` and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to evaluate it (formula returns first position on any character). Is it what you need? Or `=MIN(IFERROR(FIND({"1";"2";"3"},A1),9E+307))` - depends on local settings

Comment: @simoco that was cool sir. Please publish this as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this array formula to returns first position of any character from the list:

```
=MIN(IFERROR(FIND({"1","2","3"},A1),""))
```

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.

It returns `0` if nothing found.

Comment: I note that **for numbers** you don't need the quotes - this works as well - `=MIN(IFERROR(FIND({1,2,3},A1),""))`

Comment: thank you, barry, it's true, I've just used it for general case, when searching characters not numbers:)