# Getting specific string before a character in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, string, excel-formula, find

I wanted the leftmost string from a specific string.

Ex. `sds_djfh_jdj` I want sds for this I used the

```
LEFT('string',FIND("_",'string')-1)
```

but in my case another character may appear before the `_` character

Ex. `sds#_djfh_jdj` (I want just sds but the formula that I use will give me sds#)

Can someone tell me how do I solve the problem.

Comment: do you want a formula or vba code?

Comment: Just change to `-2` instead of `-1`

Comment: If the vba code will use too much of time then I would prefer a formula otherwise vba code would also work.

Comment: If your strings have some pattern like the "_" you can use the VBA function `Split()` which will let you split your strings into an array, starting from position 0. So, `Split(Str, "_")(0)` would be `sds`

Comment: If it's always the first 3 characters of the string you can use `Left(string, 3)`

Comment: That is the problem. The strings don't have any pattern because of which it becomes more difficult.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22556970/97581940) on how to include some `OR` logic with `FIND`. With that logic use array entered: `=LEFT(A1,MIN(IFERROR(FIND({"#";"_"},A1),""))-1)`

Comment: **Unclear**  do you want a sequence of letters to the left of either the underscore the pound symbol or to the left of any non-letter character ??

Comment: @JvdV Thanks man this works

Comment: @JvdV you might want to post it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, you can include some `OR` logic within `FIND`. For all your cases it appears that the following would do just fine:

```
=LEFT(A1,MIN(IFERROR(FIND({"#";"_"},A1)-1,LEN(A1))))
```

Note: It's an array formula and need to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: But there's one thing which causes a problem when there is just the string that I want that is sds then the formula gives an error

Comment: @AlexSebastian, please see update. If this answered your question do not forget to accept the answer (click the checkmark to the left of the answer)